# React-native app: Build failed with an exception error

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, build

I was making an app, but suddenly my app stopped working.
All apps was running properly before. But suddenly now, this happens.
Now, when I try to run app, It's giving me the error:

```
" > Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\zains\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-analytics-impl-11.8.0.aar\5f122df5deada8f908914f5bd04e05ad\jars\classes.jar "
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me about this please?

Comment: Why are you using cmd in 2019, there are so many other terminals which are there. use Gitbash

Comment: I have used Gitbash terminal but i like cmd, It's really pure and awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this :

in main project folder ,in terminal type

`cd android`

then type this

`./gradlew clean`

or try this, run this code in your project folder

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

and after that

`cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`

then build your app again

Comment: my files will be deleted?

Comment: nothing will be deleted its just a process to kill older builds and rerun the project

Comment: check the screenshot i have added in question, It's not running this " cd android && ./gradlew clean "

Comment: do `ls` inside android folder and check name of the gradlew file. if it present the now run `gradlew clean` @ZainShabir